# Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am working with Web Services, and SQL queries, and I have just gotten this error:

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d61zf1v44

I have was working with this file earlier today, and I think this is because I am working on a different PC, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Either it's corrupted or missing. Add it again. Or install it using nuget.

Comment: what is missing? add what?

Comment: the reference to the dll

Comment: i think mysql.web is missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the assembly was only on your local PC.

Add it to the project using nuget. Open the option "Manage nuget packages" and then search and install MySql.Data

---

or install the following packages via nuget console.

```
Install-Package system.web.providers
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core
```

(I had the Problem,too as I first worked on my VM, these commands solved them for me)